# Trying to put text under a picture messes up the alignment

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to get text to align under 3 images in a row. Every solution I find on here ends up putting the images in a vertical line opposed to horizontal.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="SecondFooter" class="responsiveColumn">
            <a href="link here" target="_blank"><img src="img.jpg"></a>
            <a href="link here" target="_blank"><img src="img.jpg"></a>
            <a href="link here" target="_blank"><img src="img.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#SecondFooter {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    color: #000000; 
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; 
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
}

#SecondFooter img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 155px;
    height: 155px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I've tried doing a figure and figcaption. Tried separating each image into it's own div but it just seems like anything I alter from how it looks now, puts everything into a vertical alignment and I'm trying to keep it horizontal.

Comment: Is this a typo? `<img src="img.jpg"</a>` you missed the closing bracket on the image tag

Comment: Sorry - yes it's a typo. I was just replacing the actual img links when I was putting it in here.

Comment: See my answer for solution, you need a unit on your width and height. You should edit the question to fix the typos

Comment: Edited and fixed it - thank you. Although I'm not sure how your answer helps with the text part. It's aligned how it should be. It's just once i add text, the thing starts splitting up on me.

Comment: I have no idea what text you are talking about because it is not part of the code you posted

Answer (score 0):

What about create a main div and put all the others image divs inside it? Something like

```
<div> 
   <div>
      <img>
      <p>
   </div>
   <div>
      <img>
      <p>
   </div>
   <div>
      <img>
      <p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Maybe it will do the work.

Comment: It seems like whenever the images get broken up away from the main div, it places the images in a vertical line oppose to horizontal

Comment: Try the css property `display: flex` to change this.

Comment: Okay, so putting flex on the SecondFooter ID works. Although now it's pushing the images more to the left than centering them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for? the other css is just for the visuals.

```
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
```

http://flexboxfroggy.com/ is excellent practice to show what you can achieve with flex.

https://codepen.io/garynorris88/pen/owQpvN?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you need to fix

1 - close your image tags

2 - width and height of image need a unit (px for example). 155 need to be `155px`

https://jsfiddle.net/eg5a4pjg/1/

HTML

```
<a href="link here" target="_blank"><img src="img.jpg" /></a>
```

CSS

```
#SecondFooter img{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 155px;
    height: 155px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is float your anchor tags inside your #SecondFooter div to the left like so

```
#SecondFooter a {
  float: left;
}
```

This is how your HTML should look. I added a p tag after the img tag with some text to demonstrate

```
<div id="SecondFooter" class="responsiveColumn">
  <a href="link here" target="_blank">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <p>hi there</p>
  </a>
  <a href="link here" target="_blank">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <p>hi there</p>
  </a>
  <a href="link here" target="_blank">
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <p>hi there</p>
  </a> </div>
```

To keep it all relatively centered, I added a few wrappers

HTML:

```
<div id="SecondFooter" class="responsiveColumn">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="link-wrapper">
      <a href="link here" target="_blank">
        <img src="img.jpg">
        <p>hi there</p>
      </a>
      <a href="link here" target="_blank">
        <img src="img.jpg">
        <p>hi there</p>
      </a>
      <a href="link here" target="_blank">
        <img src="img.jpg">
        <p>hi there</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS: I changed the width of SecondFooter to width: 100%;

```
#SecondFooter {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff; 
  color: #000000; 
  font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; 
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;

}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.link-wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Okay, stupid question now - how can i keep this centered? So the text is now staying under the image but it's all being pushed to the left.

Comment: I updated my solution to make it relatively centered on the screen. Go look!